# How to compare addresses of buffers in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, memory-address

I want a function that can test if the address of the start of one buffer is contained within the memory allocated of another buffer. Like so:

```
function contains(parent, child) {...}

// allocate 44 bytes
let buffer1 = Buffer.alloc(44);
// copy 44 bytes to a new address
let buffer2 = Buffer.from(buffer1);
// make reference to 8th byte of buffer1
let buffer3 = buffer1.slice(8);
// make reference to last byte of buffer2
let buffer4 = buffer2.slice(buffer2.byteLength - 1);

console.log(contains(buffer1, buffer2)); // false
console.log(contains(buffer1, buffer3)); // true
console.log(contains(buffer1, buffer4)); // false
console.log(contains(buffer2, buffer3)); // false
console.log(contains(buffer2, buffer4)); // true
console.log(contains(buffer3, buffer1)); // false - buffer1 starts outside of buffer3
console.log(contains(buffer3, buffer4)); // false
console.log(contains(buffer4, buffer2)); // false - buffer2 starts outside of buffer4
```

I have a working solution, but it requires me to iterate the entire parent buffer, and then also change values to test if they're shared. I'm looking for a solution that is O(1) or at most O(N) without manipulation needed:

```
function contains(parent, child) {
  let index = 0;

  do {
    index = parent.indexOf(child[0], index);

    if (index < 0) {
      break;
    }

    parent[index]++;

    if (child[0] === parent[index]--) {
      return true;
    }
  } while (index++ < parent.byteLength - child.byteLength);

  return false;
}
```